# protractor get element by name tag

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Currently I am working with protractor and Selenium web Driver.

I have the following problem:

I have a html page, and I make protractor clicking a button. Then a window pops up. This window contains a text box with the Name "Description":

```
<input type="Text" name="Description" ... />
```

Now when I try the following:

```
element(by.css('[name="Description"]')).sendKeys("rabbababab");
```

The browser does nothing, but protractor does not throw an error. No text is typed into the TextBox. Unfortunatelly, the name is the only way to identfy the input-TextBox.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Based on the information given there are no problems and the code should work, for me selecting element by `"[name='']"` syntax works in protractor. You may use the promise and put a custom callback function to check, whether a DOM element has bound found. http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.then

Answer (score 8):

Selecting directly by name works as well:

```
element(by.name('Description')).sendKeys("rabbababab");
```

Answer (score 2):

OK guys, ive found the issue.

It wasnt an alert, its just a div, and all other controls are locked for user Input. but the Dialog covers a TextBox, wich has the same css-properties. So protractor just writes into the covered TextBox and i couldnt see it...

The Problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes if that element is inside iframe then you have to switch to that iframe. Just check that is there any iframe or modal available?

otherwise your code seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

There is an inbuilt prompt handler in protractor where you can identify it and then send the data into the input field that you want. Here's how -

```
browser.Alert.sendKeys("rabbababab");
```

Note: The pop up window should have an input that it can accept some data into it else you command will fail.

If the above solution doesn't work then try sending data by switching to the pop-up and then sending text to it. Here's how -

```
browser.driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys('rabbababab');
```

If at all there are many prompts, then you can use window handles function to switch to the one that you want. Here's how -

```
browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function(handles){
    browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]).then(function(){ //change the array index based on your pop-up's count
        element(by.css('[name="Description"]')).sendKeys("rabbababab");
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. Since my popup contains many input boxes, is there a way to identify them ? 

Like browser.Alert.txt["name"].sendKeys(""); ??

Comment: For `Alert` object, i don't think there is any option of that kind. However you can do it using the `switchTo()` function and `getAllWindowHandles()`. Updated answer with it.

Comment: Hmmm somehow, this doesnt seem to be an alert().
Cause protractor says "no alert window"...

Its more of a Dialog.... Its weird, cause when i inspect the object its a div, so protractor should recognize it...

Comment: @AdrianMelzer does `switchTo()` window using `getAllWindowHandles()` help in identifying your pop-up? Or does it give an error too?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have multiple objects which have name="Description" in your application.
You can find this in Chrome:

1. Right-click on the object
2. Click on Inspect element
3. Press CTRL+F
4. Type [name="Description"] and see how many results it finds.

   element(by.css('[name="Description"]'))

is the same as

```
$('[name="Description"]')
```

If you find more than one, then you can try the following:
1. Try a click on the field before sending keys to it

2.

```
// This will search for the element of input with the name="Description" attribute
$('input[name="Description"]').sendKeys('rabbababab');
```

3.
You can try to put the following line, before sending keys to it :
browser.waitForAngular(); // wait until the angular app loads

Let us know how it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, 
**$('input [name=Description]')**.sendKeys("rabbababab");
or
**element(by.css('input [name=Description]'))**.sendKeys("rabbababab");

Comment: can you please add some explanation to answer for better understanding? Thanks!