# How to add value in input field in protractor using name attribute in input tag?

Tags: protractor

This is the input field:

```
<input type="text" name="_username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="">
```

This is my selector but It does not enter the value in the input field:

```
$('[name="_username"]').sendKeys('asdasda');
```

I've also tried

```
browser.element(by.css('[name="_username"]').sendKeys('asdasda');
```

but it isn't working as well. The same as

```
browser.findElement(by.css('[name="_username"]')).sendKeys('asdasda');
```

What is the correct syntax i can use to input a value in the given input field?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [protractor get element by name tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32989447/protractor-get-element-by-name-tag)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
browser.element(by.css('input[name="_username"]').sendKeys('asdasda');
```

OR

```
browser.element(by.css('input[placeholder="Username"]').sendKeys('asdasda');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var ele= element(by.css('input.form-control'));

ele.sendKeys("abc");
```

if there are more than one element try `get()` accordingly.

Hope it helps you